# TYPO3: Appearance > Layout is missing in Gridelements

Tags: typo3

For a project I'm using TYPO3 7.6.11 with fluid_styled_content and Gridelements 7.0.5.

Unfortunately the field "Layout" in "Appearance" is missing in grid elements. For every other content element the layout field is available.

I can exclude problems with other extensions. I did not override the TCA by myself and there's no problem with my page ts configuration.

What's the problem here?

I'm pleased about every hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you got two options, since the Gridelements TCE form is based on a TCA palette named "frames", which has been removed with Fluid Styled Content.

So you will either have to add the missing fields directly to the showitem section of

```
tt_content => types => gridelements_pi1
```

just as they are used in Fluid Styled Content. Or you can add the missing palette "frames" by taking the definition from CSS Styled Content and adding it to the TCA palettes of tt_content.

Both should be done in your own extension within

```
Configuration => TCA => Overrides => tt_content.php
```

And finally there is another option: Wait for the next releases of Gridelements, since they will take care of the problem automagically ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to Joey for giving the correct hint. I now extended the TCA with the following lines of code:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['palettes'] = array_replace(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['palettes'],
    [
        'frames' => [
            'showitem' => '
                layout;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:layout_formlabel,
                spaceBefore;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:spaceBefore_formlabel,
                spaceAfter;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:spaceAfter_formlabel,
                section_frame;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:section_frame_formlabel
            ',
        ]
    ]
);
```